# Cloudinary with Django - use javascript to dynamically increase/decrease photo width and height after page rendered

Tags: javascript, django, cloudinary

I have Django app where I used Cloudinary to deliver images.

The images are displayed in template with fixed width and height as follows:

```
<a href="/photo/{{ photo.id }}/">
    {% cloudinary photo.filename width=100 height=100 crop="fill" %}
</a>
```

I want to add a "+" and "-" buttons to dynamically increase and decrease photo width and height after the page is rendered.

I would have an array of possible width/height values eg 100, 125, 150, 175, 200, 225, 250, 300 or simply add 25 to 'base' width of 100 and subtract 25 to decrease width back to 100 (or use 'reset' button to reset value to 100). These would be selected by successively clicking the "+" and "-" buttons.

Ideally page doesn't reload, only Cloudinary call is made using ajax to retrieve resized photos. I am using Isotope.js to display photos in a grid which would be called to re-adjust photo layout on page.

This is not just dynamically changing width/height values of rendered photos but getting new sized photos from cloudinary.

The following script will get and render photo from Cloudinary and could replace width and height with variables:

```
$.cloudinary.image(data.result.public_id,{
    format: data.result.format, 
    width: 100, 
    height: 100, 
    crop: "fill"})
```

I imagine looping through the rendered photo elements to replace existing photos with new photos using script above.

But struggling to come up with approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the new URL you can set the width/height:

```
myWidth = 300
myHight = 300
cloudinary.CloudinaryImage("sample").build_url(
  width = myWidth, height = myHight, crop = 'fill')
```

The result will be:
http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/c_fill,h_300,w_300/sample

Comment: Ok great, while that is Python server side, it got me on different track which helped me find Cloudinary jquery `$.cloudinary.url` that I could use to create new image source with new height/width to replace existing source. I saved the Cloudinary public filename as image id. Then build new src url as: `var src_url = $.cloudinary.url(this.id + '.jpg', { width: newZoom, height: newZoom, crop: 'fill'});`